# Cycle through multiple divs with prev/next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now it cycles through 1 div per click - would it be possible to make this cycle through 4 divs with each click? Completely stumped on it...

HTML:

```
<div class="outside-buttons">
<div class="prev">Previous</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="childclass">some content</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 2</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 3</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 4</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 5</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 6</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 7</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 8</div>
<div class="childclass">some content 9</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $zDiv = $('.childclass'),
    $prNx = $('.prev, .next'),
    $btns = $('.zanc > a'),
    n = $zDiv.length,
    c = 0; // current
    d = 4; //number of items

function toggView(){ 
  // content:
  $zDiv.hide().eq(c).show(); 
  // buttons:
  $prNx.show();
 if(c<=0){
    $('.prev').hide(); 
  }
  if(c>=n-1){
    $('.next').hide(); 
    } 
}
toggView();

$prNx.click(function(){ 
  c = $(this).hasClass('next') ? ++c : --c;
  toggView();
});

$btns.click(function( e ){
   c = $(this).index();
   toggView();
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1r0ws6w/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always show 4 divs next to each other you need to raise your stepsize within your `click()` method while displaying more than one item at the same time. I used a for-loop for this purpose.
Concluding You need to adjust the condition to display/hide the next-Button accordingly.

```
var $zDiv = $('.childclass'),
    $prNx = $('.prev, .next'),
    $btns = $('.zanc > a'),
    n = $zDiv.length,
    c = 0; // current
    d = 4; //number of items

function toggView(){ 
  // content:
  $zDiv.hide();
  for(i=0;i<d && i+c<n;i++){
    $zDiv.eq(i+c).show(); 
  }
  // buttons:
  $prNx.show();
  if(c<=0){
    $('.prev').hide(); 
  }
  if(c+3>=n-1){
    $('.next').hide(); 
  } 
}
toggView();

$prNx.click(function(){ 
  c = $(this).hasClass('next') ? c += 4 : c -= 4;
  toggView();
});

$btns.click(function( e ){
   c = $(this).index();
   toggView();
});
```

This is a corresponding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/k8gwhh8c/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03cgmchk/). All you needed was where you have ++c/--c you need to add/subtract your `d` value.

```
$prNx.click(function(){ 
  c = $(this).hasClass('next') ? c += d : c -= d;
  toggView();
});
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I meant to show 4 divs initially, then scroll through them in quantities of 4...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 $prNx.click(function(){ 
  c = $(this).hasClass('next') ? c+4 : c-4;
  toggView();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `paging` for display as default number (You can set whatever number) . `c and d` will be your current start and end index of current offset .

```js
var $zDiv = $('.childclass'),
    $prNx = $('.prev, .next'),
    $btns = $('.zanc > a'),
    n = $zDiv.length,
    paging = 4;
    c = 0; // current
    d = paging; //number of items

function toggView(){
  // content:
  $zDiv.hide();
  for(var i = c; i < d; i++) {
    $zDiv.eq(i).show();
  }
  // buttons:
  $prNx.show();
  if(c == 0){
    $('.prev').hide(); 
  }
  if(c+paging >= n){
    $('.next').hide(); 
  } 
}
toggView();

$prNx.click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('next')) {
   c += paging;
   d += paging;
  } else {
    c -= paging;
    d -= paging;
  }
  toggView();
});
```

```css
.childclass {
height: 100px;
display: inline-block;
background: #e3e3e3;
margin: 10px;
}

.current { display: block; }


.childclass { clear: none !important;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
 width: 25% !Important;
 float: none;
}

.parent {
 overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap !Important;
 width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outside-buttons">
<div class="prev">
Previous</div>
<div class="next">
Next</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="childclass">
some content
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 2
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 3
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 4
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 5
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 6
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 7
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 8
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 9
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 10
</div>
<div class="childclass">
some content 11
</div>
</div>
```